# How to wait until a jQuery animation has finished before calling next functions?

Tags: jquery

I am having trouble getting my jquery function to complete, before calling the next function.

Essentially, I am trying to get my news articles to fade out, and finish all the fadeout animations before then retrieving the next page of articles via ajax.

Heres what I have (Sampled to include only the functions concerned).

A function to control the fading out of each news article...

```
function fadeArticlesOut() {
    var delay = 0;
    //set timeout for image to appear (set at 500ms)
    $('#news-articles article').each(function(index) {
        $(this).delay(delay).fadeTo(800, 0);
        delay += 400;       
    })
};
```

A function which is triggered by clicking a pagination link. This captures the url to load via ajax, but before it does so, this is where I want to run the fadeout function, i.e fadeArticlesOut.  What I want is for the fade out animations to have finished before running the loadProducts function.

```
function doPager() {
    $('.pagination-controls a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        fadeArticlesOut();          
        loadProducts($(this).attr('href'));
        history.pushState(null, null, $(this).attr('href'));
        historyedited = true;
    });
}

function loadProducts(url) {
    $('#news-articles').empty().addClass('loading').load(url + ' #news-articles-inner', function() {
        $('#news-articles').removeClass('loading');
        doPager();
        fadeArticlesIn();
    });
}
```

Once completed, the load products function will then fade in the new news articles.

So far, I have tried numerous methods including using a custom callback, deferred objects and setting timeouts. The issue I have is I can either get it to run the fadeouts, but then not continue with the ajax content load, or not have the fadeouts, but get the ajax content.

Comment: Look into deferred objects/the Promise object. You can add a .done() function handler after your fadeTo() call and that will trigger when the fade is complete.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get a promise by using `.promise()` and then add a [`.done()`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/) handler.

```
function fadeArticlesOut() {
    ...
    return $('#news-articles article').each(function(index) {
      ...
    }).promise();
};
```

```
function doPager() {
    $('.pagination-controls a').click(function(e) {
        var $self = $(this);
        ...
        fadeArticlesOut().done(function(){
            loadProducts($self.attr('href'));
        });          
        ...
    });
}
```

The `.done()` handler will be called upon all animations are completed.

Comment: Absolutely perfect, thank you.

I had tried the promise/done combination, but had missed the change in use of $(this) to $self = $(this); within my doPager function.

Solved my problem perfectly, thank you again.